# Momentjs how to get timezone time - not based on computer datetime

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I need to get the time of a time zone but not based on the computer time,I don't want the time to change when the computer or phone time changes.

I need to get the time with a zone

I have tried lot of examples available in stackoverflow and from other but is hard to find it

```
        moment.tz.setDefault("Europe/London");
        var datetime = new Date(moment());
        document.getElementById('log').innerHTML =datetime;
```

above code prints the time. When i manually change the time of my phone it's shows the changed phone time not the actual zone time.

Let say am in London and my local time 14:30 so my zone time also 14:30 when I change my phone time to 15:30 it should show actual zone time 14:30 not 15:30

Firstly is that possible? if yes please help

Comment: I think the problem is with Date, not with moment. Why do you need to convert it back to a Date object to add it to HTML?

Comment: *"when I change my phone time to 15:30"*: Do you mean you would change the time *zone* on your phone?

Comment: This is impossible to do reliably. You might use geolocation to determine the timezone, then work out the time from there, however that's quite unreliable.

Comment: I need a ticking clock of a specific zone http://jsfiddle.net/w069c8ae/2/

Comment: @trincot not the zone the time of my phone but even if i change the zone it should show according to what i have set on js

Comment: But if you change the time on your phone without changing the zone, then the time is wrong, and so any code that uses the system's clock will be wrong. So in that case I don't understand the question. If however you change the zone (and adjust the time accordingly, so it is the *right* time in that zone), there should be no problem.

Comment: @trincot simply i don't want to show a time that depend on users computer it should show a specific zone time according to a zone that is set my me.

Comment: guys can't we do something with https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/

Comment: But you are reading the system's time when you do `moment()` or `new Date()`. If you don't want that (because the device time is *wrong*), you should specify the complete date & time information and construct it. Or you should poll a timeserver out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
const datetime = moment().tz("Europe/London").format('h:mm:ss a');
// change format as needed…

console.log(datetime);

document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = datetime;
```

Make sure you have the necessary resources loaded.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dusthaines/hg1fpwue/